# How to store items of a list in class1 on another list in class2

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have two classes: Tache2new.java and Luncher.java. 
In Tache2new, I use a list named "rules" to store items.

```
public static void execute(String concept) {
List<Rule> rules = new ArrayList<>();
…
}
```

I would like to call this list in the class Luncher and store its items in ALLrules which is a list in Luncher.

To do this, I added getList() method in Tache2new (line 239). And I added in Luncher the lines ending with the comment //$$ (see the capture). But this triggered an error (highlighted in yellow in Luncher): "the local variable rules may not have been initialized".
How to fix this please?
[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I am really confused by the method you try to execute, it just returns the entered rules, which does not have any benefit. 
Could you explain, what your goal is?

Comment: Post code as text not as images!

Comment: I think you should first focus on making the Tache2new class work. Do you understand the difference between static and instance methods? Do you understand the difference between static and instance variables. Decide what you need to work with (static vs instance) and then make sure your design and code follows that decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of `getList` is wrong. It should be as follows:

```
public List<Rule> getList(){
    return rules;
}
```

Accordingly, the call inside `Launcher.excute()` will also change as follows:

```
List<Rule> rules = tech2news.getList();
```

Another problem with your implementation is that you have declared the following list inside `Tache2new.execute(...)` method

```
List<Rule> rules = new ArrayList<>();
```

You should move it out of the `Tache2new.execute(...)` method and make it instance variable inside `Tache2new` class.

Comment: I removed List<Rule> rules = new ArrayList<>(); from Tache2new.execute(...) and added it after the line: public class Tache2new {. Now I have errors inside Tache2new.execute(...) where the list rules undergoes processings.

Comment: I resolved the problem. Thank you.